# Trying to move image overlapping other image

Tags: html, css

How to move this image overlapping menu?

[image]

This "image" behind menu is with next properties:

```
.img1{
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
  height:25%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:20px;

}
```

The memu is the default menu of the theme in WordPress I'm using. 
Also I'd like to make it responsive as much as I can.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Move the menu or the image?

Comment: moving the image. menu is fine, kinda cant move it. menu is default by wordpress theme. image is the thing i want to move to overlap it.

Comment: Try setting a z-index on the image!

Comment: oh yeah that worked. i totally forgot about z-index. THANKS

Comment: No problem. I posted the answer as an 'answer' here.

Comment: You can also just put it further down in the source order and it will be on top. The further down the source the "higher" it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a z-index on the image.

Comment: also, how to make it responsive as well? now when i resize my page, its moving. :\

Comment: How do you mean it's moving?

Comment: when i resize page, to lets say 1000x500 pixels resolution, image is moving now(going more left than it should be. its not on center anymore). its not responsive, to auto-resize within page size

Comment: 1st one is how it looks like when i resize page, and 2cnd one is how its looking and how it should be. http://imgur.com/a/o6tkF#E8JiXlv

any hint how to make it reponsive ;\